# Mulitple Instagram feeds on one page

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, instagram

I have successfully put an Instagram feed for a specific user on my website, but having very little experience with PHP I cannot figure out how to simply repeat the process. I'm looking to showcase two different users, side by side in one div.

```html
<?php

// http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id/
$userid = "userid";


// http://instagram.com/developer/
$clientid = "clientid";


// http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token/
$accessToken = "token";


// number of photos to return
$count = "4";

// Gets our data
function fetchData($url){
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch); 
     return $result;
}



// Pulls and parses data.
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count={$count}");
$result = json_decode($result);

// cycles through the json tree and uses the low res url in the img tag
echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($result->data as $photo) {
        $img = $photo->images->{$display_size="thumbnail"};
        echo "<li><a href='{$photo->link}'><img src='{$img->url}' /></a></li>";

    }
    echo "</ul>";

?>
```

If I just paste the code in again, the whole page stops working. I'm guessing this is something simple, but I don't know exactly what I'm looking for! Should this code be in a separate file that is linked into my website- rather than throwing some PHP inside an HTML Bootstrap site?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I was able to get this working by using the answer below. I wanted each account to have it's own div, and the only way I know how to do that is in the html file- which would mean I still need to link to two different files. I created one file with the correct code, and another with this:

```html
<?php


// Set User ID here for different profile
//$userid = "idHere";
$userid = "296517730";

    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?client_id={$clientid}&count={$count}");
$result = json_decode($result);

// cycles through the json tree and uses the low res url in the img tag
echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($result->data as $photo) {
        $img = $photo->images->{$display_size="thumbnail"};
        echo "<li><a href='{$photo->link}'><img src='{$img->url}' /></a></li>";

    }
    echo "</ul>";





?>
```

It was working just fine on my domain, but when I moved it to my client's domain I'm getting this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/savenors/savenorsmarket.com/bostoninsta.php on line 53

What happened? I'm guessing whatever I did to get this to work wasn't really working.. but it looked fine to me. Any ideas? This is the website: http://www.savenorsmarket.com

Comment: Is there any kind of error message that's coming up when you try to run fetchData() twice? If not, do you have errors enabled in your php.ini file?

Comment: I don't have a php.ini file- should I? Like I said I rarely use php so I have no idea what I'm doing. I just have the code placed in a div on my html page (which I've saved as a .php instead to make this code work.) I don't know about error messages.. The code looks fine in my text editor (Sublime.)

Comment: Your php.ini file wouldn't be a file in your project, it would be in your php installation. Where that would be depends on how the server or locahost is set up. Try adding this to the top of your page (inside your php tags)

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

Then paste your code again to try and make two calls. If you see an error then you can debug from there. If not then you likely have a parse error which that won't catch. Might be a missing ; or something at that point.

Comment: Okay, so I added that code in. I decided to make two separate .php files for each instagram account and 'include' them into my page. Now I am seeing this error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare fetchData() (previously declared in /home/domain/public_html/folder/firstinsta.php:21) in /home/domain/public_html/folder/secondinsta.php on line 29

Comment: You're getting that because you're defining the function fetchData() in two different files.
Try this, right after the closing </ul> tag but before the ?> copy and paste this code:
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count={$count}");
$result = json_decode($result);
var_dump($result);
and see if there is any errors and what $result is.

Comment: Paste that into each separate instagram.php files?

Comment: If I paste it into just one, nothing changes. If I paste it into both, NULL appears.

Comment: Paste it all into one, and then remove the include to the second file and see if it gives you a different error.

Comment: It just shows the one feed thats in the include. No error, just "NULL"

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach is saying that the content of $result is not an array or an object. Try before your foreach() call var_dump($result)die(); and see what the output is. It may be there is an error in your API call, and therefore the data returned is not what your are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that is working on my machine pulling in twice. It pulls the same user pictures twice, but to fix this just reset the user id variable before making a second call to fetchData();

```
<?php
$userid = "idHere";


// http://instagram.com/developer/
$clientid = "IDhere";




// number of photos to return
$count = "4";

// Gets our data
function fetchData($url){
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch); 
     return $result;
}



// Pulls and parses data.
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?client_id={$clientid}&count={$count}");
$result = json_decode($result);

// cycles through the json tree and uses the low res url in the img tag
echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($result->data as $photo) {
        $img = $photo->images->{$display_size="thumbnail"};
        echo "<li><a href='{$photo->link}'><img src='{$img->url}' /></a></li>";

    }
    echo "</ul>";


// Set User ID here for different profile
//$userid = "idHere";

    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?client_id={$clientid}&count={$count}");
$result = json_decode($result);

// cycles through the json tree and uses the low res url in the img tag
echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($result->data as $photo) {
        $img = $photo->images->{$display_size="thumbnail"};
        echo "<li><a href='{$photo->link}'><img src='{$img->url}' /></a></li>";

    }
    echo "</ul>";





?>
```

Also note that I'm using the client_id over the access_token. It should work either way though.

Comment: THANK YOU! You just saved my life. That's exactly what I was trying to do but just couldn't figure out where the put that second id.

Comment: The only issue with this is that I would like to be able to separate each feed- like style each one separately. Possible?

Comment: Yea, just add a class to the ul like <ul class="images1"> and style it with css. Or you can wrap them in separate dives and style them from there.

Comment: Hey, I edited my post- I would be so grateful if you could help me out again!